# Three-phase AC regulators

Tags: power-electronics, three-phase

Can someone explain how do we end up with those integration intervals in three-phase AC regulators?

[image: Circuit and formulas]

[image: Waveforms]

Comment: Neutrals not connected ?

Comment: Is there a problem with drivers? IG6 start after IG5, IG2 & IG1 ?, IG3 & IG4 ?

Comment: @Antonio51 yes, they're not connected. I've checked multiple resources, including three books and they all have the same circuit and explanation, a bunch of integrals without additional information.

Comment: Anyway, there is a problem in "driving" ... If "neutrals" are connected, then the circuit can be seen as 3 1-phase regulators. It is what I guessed in my answer if it can help.

Comment: I will try "simulate" your configuration, but with a "driving" corrected.

Comment: Give also an eye to this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/218242/3-phase-ac-voltage-controller-question https://firstlawcomic.com/what-are-the-applications-of-three-phase-ac-voltage-controller/

Comment: @DardanLubishtani Please, can you provide the source or book for this explanation and drawing

Comment: @DuaaFalah - Hi, Your request for the source of that material is very reasonable. It has been [site policy](/help/referencing) for copied material in *answers* to be referenced for some time. More recently, this rule was clarified to include material copied into questions as well (apparently this was always intended to apply to both Q&A, but was previously ambiguous). In case the OP doesn't reply, I've done some searching and I believe that material in the question is from this book: *Power Electronics* by M D Singh and K B Khanchandani published by McGraw-Hill (or Tata McGraw-Hill in India).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what one gets when one SCR is fired.
The other can only be fired if the voltage of its Vak is positive only ...

[image]

Here when SCR bis fired at n=3, see the Load resistor voltage (VA).

[image]

And when n=6

[image]

Comment: now that I think of it we don't need those neutrals for this circuit. Supposing  T1 and T6 are conducting, we get a 0.5EAB voltage drop across the load R. If we follow the sequence shown at the bottom we will get that waveform. The thing I'm not understanding is those integral boundaries, how do we end up with those?

Comment: Ok. One "neutral is needed for the simulator. And the "driving" of SCR is not the same. When you will fire one SCR, just see if the voltage across it is "positive". Remember that the SCR already fired will conduct until the voltage across it became "negative". This will give the limits of integration of the concerned wave.

Comment: Another point. As we have 6 points "drive", and 6 points natural "stop", we have twelve "sections" of waveform on one load R. NB: With 2 sequences "drive", the strategy of "firing" seems to be a bit complicated.

Comment: I think I'm getting the idea based on your previous comment mentioning for how long the SCR will conduct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here what one get when it is a 3-phase circuit.
Ean ... does not seem to be what is in the book ...

I did 3 simulations.
One with only 1 reverse SCR fired, Second with 2 SCR fired, Third with 3 SCR fired.
One can see that waveforms are not the same ... (unless error.s)

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this one for another "drive" sequence.

[image]

Here is the calculation of "RMS voltage" versus "phase angle" drive.

[image]